# How to access ViewChild reference defined on parent component - Angular 2

Tags: angular, angular2-template

I have a spinner/loader element defined in app template (root component's template) like

```
<!--I have it here so that I don't have to paste it in all my templates-->
<div #spinner></div>
```

In my child components, I am trying to access it using `@ViewChild` but that seems to always return undefined. My code for accessing this in child component is

```
@ViewChild('spinner', { read: ViewContainerRef }) container: ViewContainerRef;  //this is always undefined
```

However when I place my `#spinner` in my child component's HTML, it gets picked up correctly.

Is there a way to get the element defined in parent component in your child component as a `ContainerRef`?

I need the view reference to create the component on it dynamically using `ComponentFactoryResolver`.

It seems a [similar](https://github.com/angular/angular/issues/5415) issue but can't find a way to overcome.

EDIT: I am now using a shared service with the observable, but still it doesn't raise an event on `.next`.

Here is my code in `SpinnerComponent`

```
@Component({
    selector: 'spinner',
    styleUrls: ['app/styles/spinner.component.css'],
    template:
    `<div [hidden]="state.visible" class="in modal-backdrop spinner-overlay"></div>
     <div class="spinner-message-container" aria-live="assertive" aria-atomic="true">
        <div class="spinner-message" [ngClass]="spinnerMessageClass">{{ state.message }}</div>
    </div>`
})
export class SpinnerComponent {

    constructor(spinnerService: SpinnerService) {
        spinnerService.spinnerStatus.subscribe(event => {
            console.log('Event: ' + event); <= not getting called
            this.state.visible = event;
        });
    }

    public state = {
        message: 'Please wait...',
        visible: false
    };
}
```

In SpinnerService, I have

```
@Injectable()
export class SpinnerService {
    public events: BehaviorSubject<boolean> = new BehaviorSubject<boolean>(false);

    public get spinnerStatus(): Observable<boolean> {
        return this.events.asObservable();
    }

    public showSpinner() {
        this.events.next(true);
    }

    public hideSpinner() {
        this.events.next(false);
    }
}
```

And in the calling component, I have

```
@Component({
    selector: 'edit-auction',
    templateUrl: '/auctions/edit.html'
})
export class EditAuctionComponent {

    constructor(public spinnerService: SpinnerService) {  }

    ngAfterViewInit() {
        //start the spinner
        this.spinnerService.showSpinner();
    }
}
```

In app.module.ts (root module)

```
@NgModule({
    imports: [BrowserModule, FormsModule, HttpModule, routes],
    declarations: [..],
    providers: [NotificationsService, SpinnerService],
    bootstrap: [AppComponent]
})
export class AppModule { }
```

Comment: As the name says, `@ViewChild` can only be used to select children. What are you trying to achieve with this? If you want to show/hide the spinner, why don't you use a custom spinner component into which you inject a service emitting events to show/hide the spinner. Check this out for an example: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42041945/1153681

Comment: IS  ngAfterViewInit called?

Comment: Yeah I added an alert just before `showSpinner` and its getting called

Comment: Is SpinnerComponent.constructor called?

Comment: No that isn't getting called! When I put it in app component, it seems to work though!

Comment: In appcomponent, it shows the spinner but it doesn't block reset of the screen. (I am using router-outlet there so that may be the case), is there a way we can instantiate the `SpinnerComponent`?

Comment: Yeah! I called `<spinner></spinner>` in main template and changed `[hidden]` to `*ngIf` and it worked! Thanks a lot :)

Comment: Quoted from @AliBaig question : "I need the view reference to create the component on it dynamically using ComponentFactoryResolver". Is there a way to access viewContainerRef of a component through Angular2 service ?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Accessing data from other components does not sounds good to me.

For what you are trying to do probably best would be to define service which will share observable:

```
@Injectable()
export class EventService {
    public selectedCategoryName: string = '';
    private events = new BehaviorSubject<Boolean>(false);
    constructor() {

    }

    public showSpinner(){
        this.events.next(true)
    }

    public hideSpinner(){
        this.events.next(false);
    }

    public get spinnerStatus() : Observable<boolean> {
        return this.events.asObservable();
    }
}
```

Then in your root component you will subscribe to

```
eventServiceInstance.spinnerStatus.subscribe(state=>{
            //thisSpinner.visible = state
        })
```

And now in all other places you will call

```
eventServiceInstance.showSpinner()
eventServiceInstance.hideSpinner()
```

PS. To make it works EventService provider should be added in NgModule and not inside of components

Comment: I agree! I am already using the shared service that is blocking the UI using dynamic component loading! To block the complete view, I didn't wanted to write component calls in my templates so I put #spinner in my root component

Comment: When I call `showSpinner()` from calling component, i doesn't raise an event in spinner component which has subscribed for it, any ideas?

Comment: @AliBaig did you add EventService provider on component or in NGModule?

Comment: Yeah my service name is `SpinnerService` and I'm importing it in `providers` in both the components

Comment: @AliBaig add them to NGModule providers then you will have same instance across all modules, because now for each module it creates you own service

Comment: I did it but strange it still doesn't notifies the subscription. I removed it from components and placed it on NGModule (just have 1 module in app). I am not subscribing in the root component, could that be an issue?

Comment: @AliBaig If you are not subscribing how it would be notified?

Comment: I meant not subscribing in the root component! I am subscribing in `SpinnerComponent`

Comment: Oh yes in SpinnerComponent its right place. To help you out please post code from spinnercomponent and from that component where you call show hide.

Comment: Ok just a minute, I'm editing my question! Thank you for taking the time to help me out

Comment: I have added the code in my question above, if you can have a look!

Answer (score 3):

Although it's better to use either `Output` parameters or a common service for this purpose its possible to inject a component from a child component by:

1. Inject the app component to the child component
2. In the app component add a `ViewChild` to the wrapper element and make it accessible
3. From the child create the new component with `ComponentFactoryResolver`  by calling `createComponent` on the wrapper element `ViewContainerRef`
4. add the loaded component to `entryComponents` of the module

code is available in [plunker](https://plnkr.co/edit/Cr1ezz?p=preview)

app.ts:

```js
@Component({
selector: 'my-app',
template: `
    <div>
    <h2>App/h2>
    <my-child></my-child>
    <div #spinner></div>
    </div>
`,
})
export class App {
@ViewChild('spinner', { read: ViewContainerRef }) private spinner: any;

public getSpinnerRef() {
    return this.spinner;
}

}
```

Child Component:

```js
@Component({
selector: 'my-child',
template: `
    <div>
    <h3>Child</h3>
    </div>
`,
})
export class ChildCmp implements OnInit {

constructor(private app: App, private componentFactoryResolver: ComponentFactoryResolver) {

}

public ngOnInit() {
    const spinnerCmp = this.componentFactoryResolver.resolveComponentFactory(SpinnerCmp);
    this.app.getSpinnerRef().createComponent(spinnerCmp);
}


}
```