# Angular 2, child to parent and back to child communication

Tags: angular

First of all thanks for your time.

I am new to Angular 2 and I am trying to understand how to solve this problem I have.

Component Structure:

```
<parent-component>
  <dynamic-button></dynamic-button>
  <dynamic-button></dynamic-button>
  ...
</parent-component>
```

Child component

```
export class DynamicButtonComponent {
  @Output() clicked: EventEmitter<any> = new EventEmitter<any>();

  loading: Boolean = false;
  handleClick(event: any) {
    this.loading = true;
    this.clicked.emit(event);
  }
};
```

When I click on the Dynamic button I am sending an event to the parent. A spinner will be shown next to the button using 'loading' variable. Parent then makes an API call, when the API call is done I would like to send a prop back to the Child component from the parent (which initially send the event) to stop showing the spinner.

Please advise what would be the best/cleanest way to solve this. I thought of having a callback to the event emitter but I read in StackOverflow that it is against Angular 2's principle

Comment: What about an @Input property bound to a parent's object that will be updated in your api's callback? https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#parent-to-child

Comment: You typically use a service to share state between components. Here's a code outline for implementing a spinner service like you described: http://stackoverflow.com/a/42041945

Comment: @AngularFrance Thanks for your reply first of all. In my scenario, every button can have a spinner component, would they be all subscribing to the same service?

Comment: Hmm. In that case, you'd have to structure the code differently. I'd still use a service, but instead of just emitting start/stop events, I would also pass some id to identify which button to start/stop. The problems with using input/output for parent-child communication are 1) it's a lot of boilerplate code for each button; 2) you might end up in a scenario where the button is not always an immediate child of the parent doing the action. Using a service lets you get around these limitations.

Answer (score 6):

You can use the OnChanges lifecycle hook to catch an @Input update on the child component to progress.

Parent:

```
export class ParentComponent {
    finishedLoading: boolean = false;
    doApiWork(){
        ...
        finishedLoading = true;
    }
}
```

Child:

```
export class DynamicButtonComponent implements OnChanges{
    @Input() loadingDone = false;

    ngOnChanges(){
        if(loadingDone){
           //Execute 
        }
    }
}
```

Bind in view:

```
<parent-component>
  <dynamic-button [loadingDone]="finishedLoading"></dynamic-button>
  ...
</parent-component>
```

Comment: That was initially my idea but couple of questions I have on that approach, 
1. Input loadingDone will be send to all the DynamicButton components when it is updated to true, how do you only send it to the relevant component, or how do you make the non-relevant ones ignore it.
2. How do you then revert back finishedLoading to false without triggering a rerendering of all the DynamicButton components

Comment: @BobinVarghese if you have a static number of DynamicButton components, then you can use a bit array you keep the state for each component.  If they are generated programmatically using *ngFor, you can use the index of the loop to make your logic decisions.