# Emitting output from ng-content to parent

Tags: angular

I'm attempting to create a wrapper for the Bootstrap split-style dropdown buttons using a button component and a dropdown component. I need to emit an output on `click` and on `document:click` from `ng-content` (which is a `<button perf-btn>`) to the parent `DropdownComponent`.

There are several similar questions, but none seem to fit my use case.

usage (app.component.html)

```
<perf-drop [data]="items">
  <button perf-btn>Default Dropdown Button</button> // click doesn't open dropdown
  <button perf-btn dropdown="true"></button>        // click opens dropdown
</perf-drop>
```

dropdown.component.html

```
<ng-content select="[perf-btn]" (notify)='onNotify($event)')></ng-content>
<ul class="dropdown-menu">
  <template ngFor let-item [ngForOf]="data">
    <li *ngIf="item.separator" role="separator" class="divider"></li>
    <li *ngIf="!item.separator" [class.disabled]="item.disabled">
      <a [routerLink]="item.path" [ngClass]="getItemColor(item.color)">
        {{item.label}}
      </a>
    </li>
  </template>
</ul>
```

dropdown.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef} from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'perf-drop',
  host: {
    '[attr.disabled]': 'disabled',
    '[class.open]': 'isOpen'
  },
  templateUrl: 'dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['dropdown.component.scss']
})
export class DropdownComponent {
  private _data: any[] = [];
  private _isOpen: boolean = false;

  @Input()
  get isOpen() { return this._isOpen; }
  set isOpen(value: boolean) { this._isOpen = value ? true : null; }

  @Input()
  get data(): any[] { return this._data; }
  set data(value: any[]) {
    this._data = value;
  }

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef) { }

  private toggle(): void {
    this._isOpen = !this._isOpen;
  }

  private close(event): void {
    if (!this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) && this._isOpen)
      this._isOpen = false;
  }

  private getItemColor(color) {
    if (color) return `text--${color}`;
  }
}
```

btn.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input, HostBinding, ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ElementRef, Renderer, EventEmitter, Output } from '@angular/core';

@Component({
  selector: 'button[perf-btn], input[perf-btn], a[perf-btn], div[perf-btn], perf-btn',
  host: {
    [snip conditional classes],
    "(click)": "_toggle()",
    "(document:click)": "_close($event)"
  },
  templateUrl: './btn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./btn.component.scss']
})
export class BtnComponent {
  [snip irrelevant fields]
  private _dropdown: boolean;
  private _state: boolean = false;

  @Input()
  get dropdown() { return this._dropdown; }
  set dropdown(value: boolean) { this._dropdown = value ? true : null; }

  get state() { return this._state; }
  set state(value: boolean) { this._state = value ? true : null; }

  [snip irrelevant getters/setters]

  @Output() notify: EventEmitter<boolean> = new EventEmitter<boolean>();

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer) { }

  _toggle() {
    console.log("notifying " + this._state);
    this._state = !this._state;
    this.notify.emit(this._state);
  }

  _close(event) {
    if (!this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) && this._state) {
      this._state = false;
      this.notify.emit(this._state);
    }
  }

  [snip irrelevant functions]
}
```

btn.component.html

```
<ng-content></ng-content>
<span class="caret" *ngIf="dropdown"></span>
```

dropdown.directive.ts

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';
import { BtnDirective } from './btn.directive';

@Directive({
  selector: `button[perf-drop], button[perf-drop], a[perf-drop], input[perf-drop],
            div[perf-drop], perf-drop`,
  host: {
    '[class.btn-group]': 'true',
    '[attr.disabled]': '[disabled]'
  }
})
export class DropdownDirective extends BtnDirective {}
```

btn.directive.ts

```
import { Directive } from '@angular/core';

@Directive({
  selector: `button[perf-btn], button[perf-btn], a[perf-btn], input[perf-btn],
            div[perf-btn], perf-btn`,
  host: {
    '[class.btn]': 'true'
  }
})
export class BtnDirective {}
```

Comment: You can't emit an output event "through" `<ng-content>` because the parent can't listen to the event.

Comment: @AngularFrance, I see... That makes things more complicated. :/

Comment: You can always inject the same service in all components that need to communicate. This way, no need for an output.

Comment: @AngularFrance, do you have any resources on how to do that?

Comment: [This code](http://stackoverflow.com/a/42041945) shows how two components - a spinner component and a standard component - communicate via a service to show/hide the spinner.

Comment: @AngularFrance, thank you! That worked perfectly. I added an answer, showing the changes I made.

Comment: You're welcome. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Thanks to @AngularFrance, I learned that `ng-content` cannot emit. However, a service can communicate between the parent component and the child `ng-content` instead.

See `// comments` for what I added to the original components to make them work with the service.

Also see [Bidirectional Communication](https://angular.io/docs/ts/latest/cookbook/component-communication.html#!#bidirectional-service) for a cookbook recipe.

btn.service.ts

```
import { Injectable } from '@angular/core';
import { Subject } from 'rxjs/Subject';
import { Observable } from 'rxjs/Observable';

@Injectable()
export class BtnService {
  private _stateSource: Subject<boolean> = new Subject<boolean>();
  public state$: Observable<Subject<boolean>> = this._stateSource.asObservable();

  public toggle(state: boolean): void {
    console.log("toggling");
    this._stateSource.next(state);
  }

  public close(): void {
    this._stateSource.next(false);
  }

  public open(): void {
    this._stateSource.next(true);
  }
}
```

dropdown.component.ts

```
import { Component, Input, ElementRef, OnDestroy } from '@angular/core';
import { Subscription }   from 'rxjs/Subscription';    // import subscription

import { BtnService } from './btn.service';            // import service

@Component({
  selector: 'perf-drop',
  host: {
    '[attr.disabled]': 'disabled',
    '[class.open]': '_isOpen'
  },
  templateUrl: 'dropdown.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['dropdown.component.scss'],
  providers: [BtnService]                              // add service as provider to parent
})
export class DropdownComponent implements OnDestroy {
  private _data: any[] = [];
  private _isOpen: boolean = false;
  private _subscription: Subscription;

  get isOpen() { return this._isOpen; }
  set isOpen(value: boolean) { this._isOpen = value ? true : null; }

  @Input()
  get data(): any[] { return this._data; }
  set data(value: any[]) {
    this._data = value;
  }

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef,
    private _service: BtnService) {                      // add to constructor
      this._subscription = _service.state$.subscribe(    // subscribe to service
        state => {
          this._isOpen = state;
        })
    }

  ngOnDestroy() {
    // prevent memory leak when component destroyed
    this._subscription.unsubscribe();
  }
}
```

btn.component.ts

```
import { Component, ViewEncapsulation, Input, HostBinding, ChangeDetectionStrategy,
  ElementRef, Renderer, EventEmitter } from '@angular/core';

import { BtnService } from './btn.service';                   // import service

@Component({
  selector: 'button[perf-btn], input[perf-btn], a[perf-btn], div[perf-btn], perf-btn',
  host: {
    "(click)": "_dropdown && _toggle()",
    "(document:click)": "_dropdown && _close()"
  },
  templateUrl: './btn.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./btn.component.scss']
})
export class BtnComponent {
  private _dropdown: boolean;
  private _state: boolean;

  @Input()
  get dropdown() { return this._dropdown; }
  set dropdown(value: boolean) { this._dropdown = value ? true : null; }

  @Input()
  get state() { return this._state; }
  set state(value: boolean) { this._state = value; }

  constructor(private _elementRef: ElementRef, private _renderer: Renderer,
    private _service: BtnService) {                      // add service to constructor
  }

  _toggle() {
    this._state = !this._state;
    this._service.toggle(this._state);                   // call service
  }

  _close() {
    if (!this._elementRef.nativeElement.contains(event.target) && this._state) {
      this._state = false;
      this._service.close();                             // call service
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: I'm not quite sure, isn't this causing problems if I am having more than one instance of the component, because the service acts as a singleton

Answer (score 11):

Although `<ng-content>` can't emit per se, the actual component behind the content can.

Indeed, the nested component can have an EventEmitter like the following :

```js
@Output()
nestedComponentChange: EventEmitter<number> = new EventEmitter<number>();
```

The parent component can then listen :

```
@ContentChildren(MyNestedComponent) templates: QueryList<MyNestedComponent>;

ngAfterContentInit() {
    this.templates.forEach((template) => {
      template.nestedComponentChange.subscribe(() => doSomething());
    });
}
```

There is no need for a service in the case above.

Comment: This absolutely worked, and should be the selected answer.

Comment: I don't get it how this works. Could you show the usage with an example please.

Comment: This is no different than a regular EventEmitter subscription, except you are listening to children component EventEmitters through `@ContentChildren`

Comment: @ojathelonius Did you set (click) on the <ng-content> element?

Answer (score 0):

Another answer would be to rely on the containing component to do the wiring, e.g. in a component called ParentComponent

```
<app-filter-bar #filterBar>
  <app-some-contents (someEvent)="callContainingComponent()"></app-some-contents>
</app-filter-bar>
```

someEvent fires, callContainingComponent is called on ParentComponent, ParentComponent calls a method on the filterBar via the ViewChild

Not as clean, you have to do the wiring explicitly each time, but simpler and the parent can now intercept the call if necessary